# Enrich RxJS observable result array with data from another request

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Considering the following simplified data structure:

**Teacher**

```js
{
  id: number,
  name: string
  students?: Student[] // filled with an inner second request
}
```

**Student**

```js
{
  name: string
}
```

**TeachersResult** (response of the first api request with no students inside)

```js
{
  teachers: Teacher[]
  pagesCount: number // metadata for the pagination
}
```

My main question is how use RxJS to fill the students-property for every teacher with these two api endpoints:

- GET `http://localhost:1337/api/teachers`
- GET `http://localhost:1337/api/students/{teacherId}`

The first idea was to start with something like this:

```js
getTeachersWithStudents(): Observable<TeachersResult> {
  return this.apiService.getTeachers().pipe(
    concatMap(teachersResult => {
      const studentsObservables$: Observable<Student[]>[] = [];
      teachersResult.teachers.foreach(teacher => 
        studentsObservables$.push(this.apiService.getStudents(teacher.id)));

      // Add students to associated teacher here? Is forkJoin() the right choice?
    });
  );
}
```

It feels complicated for me to add every students-result from the second api request to the associated teacher. This is the end result for me I want to achieve:

```js
{
  teachers: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Uncle Bob',
      students: [
        { name: 'Alice' },
        { name: 'Caren' }
      ] 
    },
    {
      ...
    }
  ],
  pagesCount: 42
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try something like this

```
getTeachersWithStudents(): Observable<TeachersResult> {
  return this.apiService.getTeachers().pipe(
    // concatMap here is right since you want to continue only after upstream
    // has notifies the list of teachers
    concatMap(teachersResult => {
      const teachers = teachersResult.teachers;
      const secondCalls = teachers.map(teacher => {
        return this.apiService.getStudents(teacher.id).pipe(
            // set the students into the teacher object and return the teacher
            // filled with the students
            map(students => {
               teacher.students = students;
               return teacher
            })
          );
      })
      // now you have an array of Observables for the second calls, you
      // can therefore use forkJoin to execute them in parallel
      return forkJoin(secondCalls).pipe(
         // add the page number
         map(teachersWithStudents => {
           return {
             teachers: teachersWithStudents,
             pagesCount: teachersResult.pagesCount
           }
         })
      )
    })
  );
}
```

In this way you are executing all the calls to get the students concurrently.

If you want to limit the concurrency rate, then you can use `mergeMap` in a slightly more complex stream, something like this

```
getTeachersWithStudents(): Observable<TeachersResult> {
  return this.apiService.getTeachers().pipe(
    concatMap(teachersResult => {
      // transform the teachers array into a stream of teachers
      const teachers = teachersResult.teachers;
      return from(teachers).pipe(
        // here you use mergeMap with the rate of concurrency desired
        // in this example I set it to 10, which means there will be at
        // most 10 requests for students on flight at the same time
        mergeMap(teacher => {
          return this.apiService.getStudents(teacher.id).pipe(
            // set the students into the teacher object and return the teacher
            // filled with the students
            map(students => {
               teacher.students = students;
               return teacher
            })
          )
        }, 10),
        // now we want to repack all the teachers in one array using toArray
        toArray(),
        // here we create the response desired and return it
        map(teachersWithStudents => {
          return {
             teachers: teachersWithStudents,
             pagesCount: teachersResult.pagesCount
          }
        })
      )
    })
  );
}
```

This [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-aqgjo2?file=index.ts) shows an example of the above 2 implementations.

Comment: Your answer was really helpful. Instead of concatMap I'm using the mergeMap operator now. If the user refreshes the list during the loading process, the last request is obsolete.

Comment: If you want the last request to be dropped if a new one comes from upstream (i.e. from the user refreshing) then I would consider to use `switchMap` rather than `mergeMap`.  You may find [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a) interesting.

Comment: Ok @Picci, I will read the article when I get a chance. Can you add some code highlighting to your answer? Then I wanna give it the checkmark.